# How can I stop my username from being displayed?

Tags: reddit

I want to stop my Reddit username from being displayed on my own screen. I want to do this in order to prevent other people who see my screen from learning my username and searching for my posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the [Reddit Enhancement Suite (RES)](http://www.redditenhancementsuite.com/) browser extension, then in Settings (gear icon at the side of Reddit preferences link) » Account » Username Hider » set to 'On'.

[image: Screenshot of UI settings described above]

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to revive almost a decade-old thread.

But in order to make this work on the new Reddit.

1. First, ensure that the UBlock Origin extension is installed in your browser.
2. Log in to your account on Reddit.
3. After navigating to the Reddit page, click on the UBlock Origin icon in your browser's toolbar to open the extension's dashboard.
4. In the UBlock Origin dashboard, click on the "Element Picker" tool. This allows you to select specific elements on a webpage.
5. Use the "Element Picker" to click on your username, which is typically located at the top right corner of the Reddit page.
6. Click on "Create" in the "Element Picker Widget". Your username will be hidden.
7. Repeat for any other element on the page.

Comment: Are you saying that the [Reddit Enhancement Suite (RES)](http://www.redditenhancementsuite.com/) option in the [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76616/197518) no longer works?

Comment: [The answer \(my answer\) with the RES solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76616/7584) still works as of 2024. (I just tried it.)

Answer (score -1):

For those using custom CSS with your browser the following CSS snippet will hide your username for both the old and new designs.

```
/* Hide Reddit username new design (2018-) */
div[class*="s1ilcdod-18 dsBbYg"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Hide Reddit username old design (pre-2018) */
span[class="user"] {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/pouriaalmassi/9c3fa191f7e1a5722c87e42784b8aa3a